# Scenario Steps(Given,When,Then) are not shown in IntelliJ console (Cucumber-Java with Junit)

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

When I am running my tests in local, I cannot see Feature-Scenario steps in my IntelliJ console. Usually you see all Given,When,And,Then steps with each scenario.

And I do have Cucumber-Java Plugin installed in IntelliJ. And IntelliJ Idea Version - IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.1
My cucumber,junit and java versions in pom:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>5.6.0</cucumber.version>
```

**RunnerTest**

```
    package io.cucumber.hellocucumber;

    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"})
    public class RunCucumberTest1 {
    }
```

**Feature File**

```
    Feature: Is it Friday yet?
      Everybody wants to know when it's Friday

      Scenario: Sunday isn't Friday
        Given today is Sunday
        When I ask whether it's Friday yet
        Then I should be told "No"

      Scenario: Friday is Friday
        Given today is Friday
        When I ask whether it's Friday yet
        Then I should be told "TGIF"
```

**Test results/output**

```
sampling ...
include patterns:
io\.cucumber\.core\.cli\..*
exclude patterns:
Jun 04, 2020 11:31:23 AM io.cucumber.core.cli.Main run
WARNING: By default Cucumber is running in --non-strict mode.
This default will change to --strict and --non-strict will be removed.
You can use --strict to suppress this warning

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
0m0.583s

Class transformation time: 0.0138887s for 1552 classes or 8.948904639175257E-6s per class

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Nidhi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using IDEA to run your Cucumber tests rather then JUnit (the RunCucumberTest1 class).

When you are using IDEA the output of your tests is grouped automatically into sections. If you expand the test results tree (you may have to toggle some filters) you can click on a step and see what was output during its execution.

If you want to see step information printed you explicitly have to enable the pretty printer. You can do this by adding `--plugin pretty` to the CLI arguments in the run configuration menu. If you add it to the template you'll only have do this once (do delete all old cucumber run configurations first).